# How to add/change ex-mode mapping in viper/vimpulse?

Tags: vim, emacs, vimpulse

really not a fan of :e and :b opening in another window, and would like to remap the functions they are calling.

Comment: AFAICT vim does not allow 'redefining' standard ex commands (:e and :b, e.g.) `:e` on my system uses the current window (you'd have to `:tabedit`, `:split`, `:vert split`) to get a different window.

Answer (score 1):

Viper ex commands are defined in `ex-token-alist`.

To add new commands (of course other approaches like consing and `add-to-list` are possible):

```
(push '("name" (do-this)) ex-token-alist)
```

Prior entries have higher priority than later, so if you want to override, just add them.